# put elements from a df by a logical vector in a new column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a pretty messy data set with mail adresses, which I would like to extract resp. put them in a new column:

```
adis_sep <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(1:3, "asdf@com.com", 5:7, "sdfg@com.com", 9, "qer@f.com", 11, 12), ncol=3, byrow = T))
adis_wo <- adis_sep %>% apply(2, function(x) grepl(".*@.*", x))
```

I managed to get a logical df for the elements I want in the new column, but now I am stucked. I know that I am missing something really obvious! So please help me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this help `grep("@", unlist(adis_sep), value = TRUE, fixed = TRUE)` ?

Comment: yes it helps with extracting all elements containing a mail address but not with the column problem.. :) but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
adis_sep%>%rowwise()%>%
  mutate(new=c(V1,V2,V3)[grep("@",c(V1,V2,V3))[1]])
Source: local data frame [4 x 4]

Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 4 x 4
  V1           V2           V3    new         
  <chr>        <chr>        <chr> <chr>       
1 1            2            3     NA          
2 asdf@com.com 5            6     asdf@com.com
3 7            sdfg@com.com 9     sdfg@com.com
4 qer@f.com    11           12    qer@f.com
```

In case more than one column has a `@`, the first one is chosen. Also, be careful when using `as.data.frame()` and add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` or this code won't work.
**edit**
For second case,

```
adis_sep%>%rowwise()%>%
  mutate(new=c(Organisation,Kontaktperson,Mail,sonst1,sonst2)[grep("@",c(Organisation,Kontaktperson,Mail,sonst1,sonst2))[1]])
Source: local data frame [2 x 6]
Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 2 x 6
  Organisation                     Kontaktperson Mail         sonst1          sonst2 new            
  <chr>                            <chr>         <chr>        <chr>           <chr>  <chr>          
1 10 Jahre xx Familienferienwochen " x y"        " adf@xx.ch" NA              NA     " adf@xx.ch"   
2 50plus talk                      " adf adf"    " führerin " " info@asdf.ch" NA     " info@asdf.ch"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but unfortunately it does not work with my original df. My original df has the dimensions 335x5, thus I take the 5 column names as the V1, V2 etc. and all of the columns are saved as characters, so this should be fine. But somehow the code does not work. It produces a new column but with no elements in it. Can you help me there too?

Comment: could you maybe post a `dput(head(adis_sep))` ?

Comment: Uh, I think I can not do that, because of the names and mail addresses of the persons.. :/ but what exactly do you want to know about the df?

Comment: Well I don't know how else I could help you. If my code works in the sample you provided and not in your `df`, there must be something different in it. Maybe do the `dput` and change those mail adresses?

Comment: > dput(head(adis_sep, n=2))   structure(list(Organisation = c("10 Jahre xx Familienferienwochen","50plus talk"), Kontaktperson = c(" x y", " adf adf"), Mail = c(" adf@xx.ch", " führerin "), sonst1 = c(NA, " info@asdf.ch"), sonst2 = c(NA_character_,NA_character_)), .Names = c("Organisation", "Kontaktperson","Mail", "sonst1", "sonst2"), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")

Comment: Ah, it works for me too!! :) I accidentally put the column names in quotation marks! thanks for your help! really appreciated it!

Comment: No problem, if this answered your question do accept it as correct answer